# Accessing created DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have code to create another "row" (div with inputs) on a button click.  I am creating new input elements and everything works fine, however, I can't find a way to access these new elements.

Example:  I have input element (name_1 below). Then I create another input element (name_2 below), by using the javascript's `createElement` function.

```
<input type='text' id='name_1' name="name_1" />
<input type='text' id='name_2' name="name_2" />
```

Again, I create the element fine, but I want to be able to access the value of name_2 after it has been created and modified by the user.  Example: `document.getElementById('name_2');`

This doesn't work.  How do I make the DOM recognize the new element?  Is it possible?

My code sample (utilizing jQuery):

```
function addName(){
var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");
$(parentDiv).attr( "id", "lp_" + id );

var col1 = document.createElement("div");
var input1 = $( 'input[name="lp_name_1"]').clone(true);
$(input1).attr( "name", "lp_name_" + id );
$(col1).attr( "class", "span-4" );
$(col1).append( input1 );

$(parentDiv).append( col1 );

$('#main_div').append(parentDiv);
}
```

I have used both jQuery and JavaScript selectors.  Example: `$('#lp_2').html()` returns null.  So does `document.getElementById('lp_2');`

Comment: Can you post sample code? I don't see why this shouldn't work...maybe I am missing something though

Comment: I added it to my post.  I use a jQuery selector to get to any of the elements AND straight JavaScript and neither gets me the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the element AND add it to the DOM using functions such as appendChild.  See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_methods.asp) for details.

My guess is that you called createElement() but never added it to your DOM hierarchy.

Comment: I am using jQuery's append( content ) function for adding my new elements.  According to the documentation it is the same as appendChild().  Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If it's properly added to the dom tree you will be able to query it with document.getElementById.  However browser bugs may cause troubles, so use a JavaScript toolkit like jQuery that works around browser bugs.

Comment: I am actually using jQuery, but I didn't think I needed to add that to the question.  jQuery has been a big help though.

Comment: Can you obtain the element by using jQuery selectors, i.e. $("#name_2") instead of getElementById()?  If not, that would at least help eliminate browser issues.

Comment: I have tried both to no avail.  Example: $('#lp_2').html().  (null)

Answer (score 0):

> var input1 = $( 'input[name="lp_name_1"]').clone(true);

The code you have posted does not indicate any element with that name attribute.  Immediately before this part, you create an element with an **id** attribute that is similar, but you would use `$("#lp_1")` to select that, and even that will fail to work until you insert it into the document, which you do not do until afterwards.

Comment: The input element with a name of lp_name_1 is part of the page in its original form.  I'm cloning that element to allow for a second name to be entered.  The first name field will always be there.  Another thing, creating the elements works, getting to them after doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input1 = $( 'input[name="lp_name_1"]').clone(true);
```

should be

```
var input1 = $( 'input[@name="lp_name_1"]').clone(true);
```

Try that first, check that input1 actually returns something (maybe a debug statement of a sort), to make sure that's not the problem.

Edit: just been told that this is only true for older versions of JQuery, so please disregard my advice.

Comment: That's xPath syntax, it's unnecessary and hasn't worked in jQuery for a long time.

Comment: Oh cool, didn't realize that. Was playing around with a demo earlier, and the query wouldn't work without the @. Just double-checked and the site was using an older version of jquery, which explains it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answers.  After walking away and coming back to my code, I noticed that I had made a mistake.  I had two functions which added the line in different ways.  I was "100% sure" that I was calling the right one (the code example I posted), but alas, I was not.

For those also experiencing problems, I would say all the answers I received are a great start and I had used them for debugging, they will ensure the correctness of your code.

My code example was 100% correct for what I was needing, I just needed to call it. (Duh!)

Thanks again for all your help,

-Jamie